# How to get GNU `find` to not display the initial path?

Tags: bash, find

Is there a built-in way for `find` to not display the initial path in the results? Ideally a built-in option or a simple `-printf` argument.

For example, `find initial/path` returns:

```
initial/path/file1
initial/path/dir1/file1
initial/path/dir1/file2
```

I would like to just have:

```
file1
dir1/file1
dir1/file2
```

Things I've tried:

1) `cd` to the initial path first.

```
cd initial/path
find
```

But that gives `./file1`, it still includes an extra `./`

2) `find initial/path | sed 's,^initial/path/,,'`

This works, but it just seems to be unnecessary/extra processing if there is a better way.

Comment: `find` is not part of bash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU `find`:

```
find some/dir -printf '%P\n'
```

More info

```
%P    File's  name  with  the  name of the starting-point under
      which it was found removed.
```